# How to prevent modification of DLL file in Java before loading it through JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, locking

I need to prevent any kind of modification of a dll file before I verify it's signature certificate (so there is no race condition, where someone could swap the dll at any point between verification and actual dll load). Is there any way in Java to prevent writes to a file that is certiain?

Comment: Load it first and then checkl the signature? and abort if it doesn't match?

Comment: Still race condition: dll tampered with -> dll loaded -> someone puts back correct dll -> it is verified OK

Comment: No. Once the DLL is loaded it is locked by the operating system and cannot be replaced, and, even if it could, the one you are calling is the one you loaded.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification, but the file can be replaced after the load (in some nasty way) and I could be verifying certificate of different file, right?

Comment: Wrong, for all the reasons I have already mentioned.